# C# EWS Subject return Organizer and Body is null

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

When I use code

```
calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(ExServices, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
```

Appointment that create by program return correct (Subject & Body is shown)
(But room cannot be change, always testroom@email.com due to not set room)

But when I use code

```
FolderId cfFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "testroom@email.com");
calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(ExServices, cfFolderId, new PropertySet());
```

Subject return Organizer Name and Body is null.

***ExServices has set to user that has authorize to all room.

I already set Full Authorize to user that use for create Appointment. Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only code your showing is binding to Calendar folder you don't show the code you use to access the Items. However your issue sounds like the normal Meeting room configuration. Eg by default Meeting rooms will replace the Subject with Organiser name (for security reasons) controlled via the -AddOrganizerToSubject "The AddOrganizerToSubject parameter specifies whether the meeting organizer's name is used as the subject of the meeting request. Valid input for this parameter is $true or $false. The default value is $true." re https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046(v=exchg.160).aspx . The body is controlled via the DeleteComments parameter "The DeleteComments parameter specifies whether to remove or keep any text in the message body of incoming meeting requests.". The reason these setting are configured this way on Meeting rooms is that everybody generally has read access to them but for instance you don't generally want all the staff to know the details of the meetings being held (eg meeting to discuss layoffs etc)